# What's the difference between deleteBeforeReplace passed into the constructor vs diff?

Tags: pulumi

`pulumi.dynamic.ResourceProvider`'s constructor takes a `deleteBeforeReplace` option but so does its `diff()` method.

- What is the difference between the two options?
- Why is the user asked to specify this twice?
- Do they do different things?

Comment: fairly certain outcome would be the same

Comment: @4c74356b41 So when does one apply, and when does the other's value take over? :)

Comment: take over doesnt make a lot of sense if the outcome is identical, right?

Comment: @4c74356b41 It makes a difference. If one passes `false` into the constructor but `true` out of `diff()` it's not clear what will happen.

Comment: well, if you want to shoot yourself in the leg, go ahead